# Unable to deploy hello world contract using soroban cli tool

Tags: stellar-sdk, smart-contract, cli

i tried using command - soroban contract deploy   --wasm target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/soroban_nft.wasm   --source alice   --network futurenet

```
Caused by:
HostError: Error(WasmVm, InvalidInput)

Event log (newest first):
   0: [Diagnostic Event] topics:[error, Error(WasmVm, InvalidInput)], data:["contract pre-release number for old protocol is nonzero", 27]
```

I tried on futurenet and test net both

used soroban --version  --   soroban 20.0.0-rc4

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.